# Disabling hotkeys in Desktop Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

Before you start criticizing, I'd like you to know that I have a really reasonable reason to disable hotkeys :

I'm coding a small video game in Javascript, a guitar hero like that's played using an inverted keyboard. And it uses various keys on the key board (F1 to F5 by default, mac users can change it in the options panel) while other keys aren't disabled.

The problem resides in the F5 keys (and any other key if the user selected it). On Firefox and Google chrome, I could simple use `event.preventDefault();` or `window.event.returnValue = false;`. But these two methods have no effect on Windows' Safari.

I'd like to know if there's any way to do it. I have an alternative but i'd rather use it as a last resort...

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35849) in WebKit.

Comment: Oh thanks :D Seems like I don't have to worry about it anymore.